# Как конвертировать коллекцию Map в Set и наоборот?

Tags: javascript, map, set

На [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/map-set#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%8C.) пишется, что метод `forEach()` может иметь 2 параметра в качестве `value`.

Для чего? Пишется, что...

> Это сделано для совместимости с объектом Map, в котором колбэк forEach
> имеет 3 аргумента. Выглядит немного странно, но в некоторых случаях
> может помочь легко заменить Map на Set и наоборот.

Также `set.keys()` – это то же самое, что и `set.values()`. Пишется, что это тоже используется для совместимости коллекций Map и Set.

Вопрос: Как конвертировать Map в Set и наоборот? Не могу найти информацию

Answer (score 0):

До появления `Map` и `Set` был только массив, соответственно существует много кода, в котором массив используется там, где на самом деле нужны `Map`, либо `Set`.

Для того, чтобы не пришлось много переписывать, интерфейсы перебора для коллекций `Map` и `Set` сделали такими же как и для массива.

Поэтому вместо переписывания кода самого алгоритма, достаточно просто передать объект другого типа.

Comment: _"Поэтому вместо переписывания кода самого алгоритма, достаточно просто передать объект другого типа."_ что значит "просто передать объект другого типа"?

Comment: @Ivan, вместо `[1,2,3]` будут передавать `new Set([1,2,3])` - например